# Cancel on confirm still submits form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with a submit and cancel button and I want to show a different `confirm` message bepending on which button is clicked so this is what I've come up with.

```
function confirmDialog(buttonId) {
    switch (buttonId) {
        case "cancel":
            var result = confirm("cancel message");
            submitForm(result);
            break;
        case "submit":
            var result = confirm("Submit message");
            submitForm(result);
            break;
    }
};
```

And my `submitForm` function looks like

```
function submitForm(result) {
    console.log(result); //this is false when I click cancel in the confirm box
    if (result && $("#myform").valid()) {
        $("#myform").submit();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Now my issue is that when I click cancel the form still gets submited. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please. I have `return false;` in my `else` condition so I really don't know why it still submits the forms.

I've looked at the following questions but I'm still facing the issue

[jQuery Still Submits Ajax Post Even When “Cancel” is clicked on Confirm Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051989/jquery-still-submits-ajax-post-even-when-cancel-is-clicked-on-confirm-dialog)

[javascript confirm (cancel) still submits form when returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988915/javascript-confirm-cancel-still-submits-form-when-returning-false)

**Edit:** Cancel button html as requested

```
<button type="submit" id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
```

**Further Edit**

I call the `confirmDialog` function in the click event the appropriate button as follows:

```
 $("#cancel").click(function () {
    var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
    confirmDialog(buttonId)
});
```

Comment: please post your html code and from where you are calling confirmDialog funciton?

Comment: Looks like because if you click cancel so `confirmDialog('cancel')` runs, and then in the confirm dialogue you click "OK", this will send a bool `true` value to the `submitForm` function?

Comment: Please post your html code. I would like see how you declared your `Cancel` button

Comment: @DavidR I've updated my question

Comment: @Stu If I click on the `Cancel` button with the id of `#cancel` then I will get the `confirm ("cancel message")` alert. From which I click cancel and this is where the form submits. In my `console.log(result)` is false so it should not submit the form

Comment: test the `form.valid()` in console.

Answer (score 2):

your button have default behavior of submit

replace

```
<button type="submit" id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
```

with

```
<button id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
```

... Edit after your update Try this code ....

replace your code

```
function submitForm(result) {
    console.log(result); //this is false when I click cancel in the confirm box
    if (result && $("#myform").valid()) {
        $("#myform").submit();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

with

```
   function submitForm(result) {
    console.log(result); //this is false when I click cancel in the confirm box
    if (result && $("#myform").valid()) {
        $("#myform").submit();
    }
    else {
       const element = document.querySelector('myform');
element.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log('Form submission cancelled.');
});
    }
};
```

----- Alternative working code if you consider changing your HTML structure ---

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="MyForm">
        <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#MyForm').submit();
            });
            $("#btnCancel").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var result = confirm("Sure Cancel?");
                if (result) {
                    const element = document.querySelector('#MyForm');
                    element.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                    alert("Form Submission Canceled");
                }
                else {
                    $("#MyForm").submit();
                    alert("Form Submitted");
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: from where you are calling confirmDialog function?

Comment: The `confirmDialog` is called int the click event of the appropriate button

Comment: do you have return functionName into you form attribute like <form onSubmit = return functionName>

Comment: You code snippet only works the first time, the second time the form is not submmited. i.e. if I click cancel on the confirm message and then ok next time it does not submit the form

Comment: that mean your code still go into else when you click ok second time?

Comment: Yes I can see the `'Form submission cancelled` in the console

Comment: make sure your if condition is proper, result will return true but your validate function needs to be checked.. Once you get it my code will work perfectly for you. :)

Comment: see my alternative solution if you consider changing your html structure..

Answer (score 0):

The form submit is only omitted when "onsubmit" gets "false" from the Javascript handler.

Try this

1. "return submitForm..." (instead of just "submitForm...")

(2. Remove semicolons after function's closing brackets)

**Update**

Maybe the problem is the combination of `input type=submit` and `$("#myform").submit();`

If `<form onsubmit=...` receives no `false` (for example from a function return), the form **will** be submitted.

If `<input type=submit onclick=...` receives no `false` (for example from a function return), the button action (form submission) **will** be performed.

Raw (unchecked) solution option without using `input type=submit`:

HTML

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="formValidation()">
    <button value="Submit" onclick="buttonHandler(true)">
    <button value="Cancel" onclick="buttonHandler(false)">
</form>
```

JS

```
function formValidation()
{
    return $("#myform").valid();
}

function buttonHandler(isSubmit)
{
    if (isSubmit ==== true)
    {
        if (confirm(submitMessage) === true)
        {
            $("#myform").submit();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (confirm(cancelMessage) === true)
        {
            $("#myform").submit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after submitForm function?

Comment: After each function, function definitions just need semicolons when assigned as var x = function() {}; Otherwise they are at least obsolete / not needed. (as far as I know)

Comment: Thanks but I still have the same issue after trying your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and solved it with click event, which is very similar to your problem.

Try this:

```
 $("#cancel").click(function () {
    var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
    confirmDialog(buttonId);

    return false;
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Your `<button>` tag's `type` attribute seems to have `submit` as its value, just remove the `type="submit"` attribute in your HTML code and keep it just `<button id="cancel".... />`

```
<button id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" value="Cancel">Cancel</button>
```

This will resolve your issue. Hope this helps!

Comment: I've just tried this and I still get the same issue :/

Comment: Can you please try clearing your browser cache and execute the page once again?

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: The default type for `<button>` is `submit`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get this to work if you use an input tag instead of button tag and retain your styles by keeping your classes. e.g.

```
<input id="SomeId" 
class="btn btn-danger btn-block" 
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete: X');"
value="Delete" />
```